# record image effects as animations

Tags: video, images, imagemagick, animation

I've done only some very basic stuff with ImageMagick (mainly resizing, also messing with color filters a bit).

Imagemagick has a simple example for overlaying images:

```
  convert anthony_1.jpg anthony_2.jpg -average  anthony_ghosts.jpg
```

But I have no idea how to do this in an animated way. An example (with explanation) for ImageMagick or another program would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to create an animated gif?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yeah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no ImageMagick expert either, so there must be better than this example:

```
convert -pointsize 72 label:ByeBye -resize 300x100! /tmp/b.gif
convert -pointsize 72 label:Hello -resize 300x100! /tmp/a.gif
for i in $(seq 10)
do   composite -blend ${i}0 /tmp/b.gif /tmp/a.gif /tmp/c${i}0.gif
done
convert -delay 50 -dispose None /tmp/c?0.gif /tmp/c100.gif -loop 3 /tmp/out.gif
display /tmp/out.gif
```

We create 2 small gifs holding some text, then use `-blend` with a value of 10% to 100% to create files `c10.gif` to `c100.gif`. These are joined into an animation with a delay of 50/100th seconds per frame, looping 3 times. See [animation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/) and [compose](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/).

[image]